# Numpy array transform using self elements without for loop

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to transform all elements in a numpy array the following way:

```
x = np.array([1,2,3,6])
... some transformation
y = np.array([1, 0.5, 0.66, 0.5])
```

Where the rule is:

```
y[i]=x[i]/x[i+1]
```

But I can't use a for loop or while.

I don't see how I could use map or vectorize in this case. Any idea?

EDIT: The final goal is to get from a time serie the numpy array containing the returns instead of the values themselves
Have edited the values of y since they were incorrect

Comment: What do you do for the last i, where i+1 doesn't exist?

Comment: good question, I guess I'll get a NaN or inf, but that would be ok

Comment: Sorry, but I'm really not seeing how you get that output for `y`. What am I missing?

Comment: @roganjosh i think its just an example of a transformation. Not necessarily the one needed

Comment: Yeah, that makes no sense. Voting to close as unclear what you're asking.

Comment: I'm kinda guessing so too, but for an example of 4 numbers, I don't see why it couldn't be specific.

Comment: gonna edit.... I want to calculate the return of a time serie

Comment: @roganjosh it could be Vincent might need more than one transformation. So maybe a flexible solution is best

Comment: edit: The final goal is to get from a time serie the numpy array containing the returns instead of the values themselves

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this.

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([1,2,3,6])
y = x / np.r_[x[1:],x[0]]

print(y)
```

outputs

```
>>> y
[0.5        0.66666667 0.5        6.        ]
```

Or this might be faster but has the same idea:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([1,2,3,6])
y = x / np.roll(x, -1)
print(y)
```

outputs

```
>>> y
[0.5        0.66666667 0.5        6.        ]
```

Comment: perfect, roll was what I needed! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You should use vectorised functionality. Since the last element will always be  `np.nan`, you can use `np.hstack` to append this.

```
x = np.array([1,2,3,6])

res = np.hstack((x[:-1] / x[1:], np.nan))

# array([ 0.5       ,  0.66666667,  0.5       ,         nan])
```

I assume the definition of `y` in your question is incorrect, as it does not match the formula you have provided.

Comment: Nice and you are right about y. However I get the following error: ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions

Comment: @VincentTeyssier, I can't replicate your error. You can check `x.shape` and see if you really have a 1d array. Or [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50027783/edit) your question to make it a [mcve]. I recommend the latter if you don't want this question to get closed.

Comment: forgot to comment a reshape in my code, you are right about how to make my question but unfortunately I can't really show more, it would be too complex and too long ;)